# Flutter Widget Test Fail

Tags: flutter

***ModelWidget***

```js
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ModelWidget<T extends ChangeNotifier> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, T model, Widget child) builder;
  final T model;
  final Widget child;
  final Function(T) onModelReady;

  ModelWidget({
    Key key,
    this.builder,
    this.model,
    this.child,
    this.onModelReady,
  }) : super(key: key);

  _ModelWidgetState<T> createState() => _ModelWidgetState<T>();
}

class _ModelWidgetState<T extends ChangeNotifier>
    extends State<ModelWidget<T>> {
  T model;
  Timer buildInitReady;

  @override
  void initState() {
    model = widget.model;

    if (widget.onModelReady != null) {
      buildInitReady = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 50), () {
        widget.onModelReady(model);
      });
    }

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    buildInitReady.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<T>(
      create: (context) => model,
      child: Consumer<T>(
        builder: widget.builder,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***LoginViewModel***

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:katsuma_go/core/configs/constant.dart';
import 'package:katsuma_go/core/configs/locales.dart';
import 'package:katsuma_go/core/services/storage.dart';
import 'package:katsuma_go/data/models/authentication_model.dart';
import 'package:katsuma_go/data/store/authen_store.dart';
import 'package:local_auth/local_auth.dart';

class LoginViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  AuthenStore _authenStore;
  final passwordControl = TextEditingController();
  final usernameControl = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode userFocus;
  FocusNode passwordFocus;
  bool userWarning = false;
  bool passwordWarning = false;
  AccountModel storedAccount;
  LocalAuthentication localAuth;
  bool canFingerPrint = true;
  bool shouldRememberPassword = true;
  Future<bool> finger(context) async {
    try {
      bool didAuthenticate = await localAuth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
          localizedReason: KatLocalizations.of(context).bioAuthenRequest);
      print('did verify $didAuthenticate');
      return didAuthenticate;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }

  LoginViewModel({@required AuthenStore authenStore}) {
    _authenStore = authenStore;
    userFocus = FocusNode();
    passwordFocus = FocusNode();
    localAuth = new LocalAuthentication();
    checkFingerPrintAvaible();
  }

  loginPress(context) async {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());

    if (usernameControl.text == '' || passwordControl.text == '') {
      userWarning = usernameControl.text == '';
      passwordWarning = passwordControl.text == '';
      notifyListeners();
    }
    var authenDigest = await _authenStore.login(
        userName: usernameControl.text, password: passwordControl.text);
    if (authenDigest) {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, RoutePath.Splash);
    }
  }

  void checkFingerPrintAvaible() async {
    canFingerPrint = await localAuth.canCheckBiometrics;
  }

  void initStoredAccount(context) async {
    storedAccount = await _authenStore.getAccountInStorage();
    getRememberPassword();
    usernameControl.text = storedAccount.userName;
    if (storedAccount.password != '') {
      fingerPrompt(context);
    }
  }

  void usernameDone(context) {
    userFocus.unfocus();
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(passwordFocus);
  }

  void passwordDone(context) {
    passwordFocus.unfocus();
    loginPress(context);
  }

  void fingerPrompt(context) async {
    bool fingerAuthenSafe = await finger(context);
    if (fingerAuthenSafe) {
      passwordControl.text = storedAccount.password;
      loginPress(context);
    }
  }

  void setRememberPassword(bool flag) {
    shouldRememberPassword = flag;
    StorageService.instance.saveSecure(StorageKey.REMEMBER_PASSWORD, flag);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void getRememberPassword() async {
    var remeberCache =
        await StorageService.instance.getSecure(StorageKey.REMEMBER_PASSWORD);
    print('the cached tick poassword $remeberCache');
    shouldRememberPassword = remeberCache != false;

    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    userFocus.dispose();
    passwordFocus.dispose();
  }
}
```

***LoginScreen***

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:katsuma_go/UI/widgets/model_widget.dart';
import 'package:katsuma_go/core/configs/flavor_config.dart';
import 'package:katsuma_go/core/configs/locales.dart';
import 'package:katsuma_go/data/store/authen_store.dart';
import 'package:katsuma_go/data/view_model/login_VM.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AuthenStore authStore = Provider.of<AuthenStore>(context);
    return ModelWidget(
      model: LoginViewModel(authenStore: authStore),
      onModelReady: (LoginViewModel model) async {
        model.initStoredAccount(context);
      },
      builder: (context, LoginViewModel model, Widget child) => Container(
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/sky2.jpeg'),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                color: Colors.white,
                colorBlendMode: BlendMode.softLight,
              ),
            ),
            Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30.0,
                    ),
                    Image(
                      image: AssetImage(FlavorConfig.instance.values.logoAsset),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      height: 150.0,
                    ),
                    Form(
                      child: Theme(
                        data: ThemeData(
                            brightness: Brightness.light,
                            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
                            inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.blueAccent, fontSize: 20.0))),
                        child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 50.0, vertical: 5.0),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              InputLogin(
                                key: Key('usernameInput'),
                                controller: model.usernameControl,
                                isError: model.userWarning ||
                                    authStore.errorMsg != '',
                                label:
                                    KatLocalizations.of(context).loginUsername,
                                placeholder: KatLocalizations.of(context)
                                    .loginUsernamePlaceHolder,
                                isPassword: false,
                                focusNode: model.userFocus,
                                onSubmitKeyboard: (term) =>
                                    model.usernameDone(context),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 20.0,
                              ),
                              InputLogin(
                                key: Key('passwordInput'),
                                controller: model.passwordControl,
                                isError: model.passwordWarning ||
                                    authStore.errorMsg != '',
                                label:
                                    KatLocalizations.of(context).loginPassword,
                                placeholder: KatLocalizations.of(context)
                                    .loginPasswordPlaceHolder,
                                isPassword: true,
                                focusNode: model.passwordFocus,
                                onSubmitKeyboard: (term) =>
                                    model.passwordDone(context),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 50.0,
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Checkbox(
                                        onChanged: (bool value) {
                                          model.setRememberPassword(value);
                                        },
                                        value: model.shouldRememberPassword,
                                      ),
                                      Text(KatLocalizations.of(context)
                                          .rememberPassword)
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              authStore.isLoading
                                  ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                                  : Column(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: double.infinity,
                                          child: RaisedButton(
                                            key: Key('loginBtn'),
                                            color: Colors.blue,
                                            shape: StadiumBorder(),
                                            onPressed: () =>
                                                model.loginPress(context),
                                            child: Text(
                                              KatLocalizations.of(context)
                                                  .signin,
                                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        if (model.canFingerPrint &&
                                            model.storedAccount?.password !=
                                                null &&
                                            model.storedAccount.password != '')
                                          IconButton(
                                            iconSize: 48.0,
                                            icon: Icon(Icons.fingerprint),
                                            onPressed: () =>
                                                model.fingerPrompt(context),
                                          ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                              Container(
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  authStore.errorMsg,
                                  key: Key('errorMsg'),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.red, fontSize: 16.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InputLogin extends StatelessWidget {
  final controller;
  final placeholder;
  final isPassword;
  final label;
  final bool isError;
  final ValueChanged<String> onSubmitKeyboard;
  final FocusNode focusNode;

  const InputLogin({
    Key key,
    this.controller,
    this.placeholder,
    this.isPassword,
    this.label,
    this.isError = false,
    this.onSubmitKeyboard,
    this.focusNode,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: TextField(
            controller: controller,
            focusNode: focusNode,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            cursorColor: Colors.red,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: label,
              hintText: placeholder,
              labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(48, 45, 143, 1)),
              errorText: isError ? '' : null,
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            obscureText: isPassword,
            textInputAction:
                isPassword ? TextInputAction.done : TextInputAction.next,
            onSubmitted: onSubmitKeyboard,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

***Login Test***

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:katsuma_go/UI/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:katsuma_go/UI/widgets/model_widget.dart';
import 'package:katsuma_go/data/store/authen_store.dart';
import 'package:katsuma_go/data/view_model/login_VM.dart';
import 'package:katsuma_go/provider_setup.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  
  Widget _makeTestable(Widget _child) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: AuthenStore(),
      child: _child
    );
  }

  var userNameField = find.byKey(Key("usernameInput"));
  var passwordField = find.byKey(Key("passwordInput"));
  var loginInButton = find.byKey(Key("loginBtn"));

  group('Login Screen Test', () {
    testWidgets('username, password and button are found', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(_makeTestable(LoginScreen()));
      expect(userNameField, findsOneWidget);
      expect(passwordField, findsOneWidget);
      expect(loginInButton, findsOneWidget);
      
    });
  });
}
```

***Run test has been failed.***

```js
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Consumer<LoginViewModel>(dirty, dependencies:
[InheritedProvider<LoginViewModel>]):
The getter 'values' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: values

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Consumer<LoginViewModel> file:///C:/Works/Projects/katsuma-go/lib/UI/widgets/model_widget.dart:51:14

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      LoginScreen.build.<anonymous closure> (package:katsuma_go/UI/screens/login.dart:40:63)
#2      Consumer.build (package:provider/src/consumer.dart:180:12)
#3      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4291:28)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4223:15)
#5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#6      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#7      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#8      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#10     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#11     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#12     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#13     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#14     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#15     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#16     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#17     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#18     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#19     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
#20     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#21     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#23     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#24     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#25     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#26     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
#27     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#28     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#29     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#30     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#31     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#32     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#33     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#34     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#35     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#36     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#37     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#38     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#39     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#40     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#41     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#42     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
#43     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#44     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
#45     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
#46     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
#47     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
#48     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
#49     RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1028:16)
#50     RenderObjectToWidgetElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1006:5)
#51     RenderObjectToWidgetElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1020:7)
#52     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
#53     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2432:33)
#54     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:974:18)
#55     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:283:5)
#56     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1102:15)
#57     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1041:9)
#58     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.pump.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:872:9)
#61     TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:69:41)
#62     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.pump (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:859:27)
#63     WidgetTester.pumpWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:323:22)
#66     TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:69:41)
#67     WidgetTester.pumpWidget (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:320:27)
#68     main.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/Works/Projects/katsuma-go/test/UI/screens/login_test.dart:87:20)
#70     main.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/Works/Projects/katsuma-go/test/UI/screens/login_test.dart:82:60)
#71     testWidgets.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:124:25)
#73     testWidgets.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:122:9)
#74     TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTestBody (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:696:19)
#88     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1066:17)
#90     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1054:35)
(elided 35 frames from class _FakeAsync, package dart:async, package dart:async-patch, and package stack_trace)

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown running a test:
The getter 'values' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: values

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      main.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/Works/Projects/katsuma-go/test/UI/screens/login_test.dart:89:63)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      testWidgets.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:124:25)
#3      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTestBody (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:696:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:679:14)
#7      AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1050:24)
#13     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1047:15)
#14     testWidgets.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:121:22)
#15     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:171:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:242:15)
#21     Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:239:5)
#22     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:169:33)
#27     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:168:13)
#28     Invoker._onRun.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:392:25)
#42     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:384:19)
#43     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:418:5)
#44     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)
(elided 28 frames from class _FakeAsync, package dart:async, package dart:async-patch, and package stack_trace)

The test description was:
  username, password and button are found
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following message was thrown:
Multiple exceptions (2) were detected during the running of the current test, and at least one was
unexpected.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Test failed. See exception logs above.
The test description was: username, password and button are found

✖ Login Screen Test username, password and button are found
Exited (1)
```

**Description:**
1- I wrote a Widget test for login testing. I posted my source code above.
2- When I run this test, I encounter error:

**"The getter 'values' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: values" error**

I also posted the details of error above.

Can you guide me how to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: A tip for the future: `ctrl + f` for what the error mentions in your code. There is only one instance of `values` in your code so you problem must be there. The error suggests that `FlavorConfig.instance` is returning a `null` object.

Answer (score 0):

`NoSuchMethodError X was called on null` occurs when the variable or the method that you're trying to call may have yet to be initialized. Ensure that **FlavorConfig** is initialized before calling `FlavorConfig.instance.values`.